# Automate Web Browser control in Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, browser-automation

I want to know if its possible to automate the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and make it running in multiple threads.

I mean I want to login to say mysite.com , using 5 different accounts, Is it possible to do that simultaneously with 5 web browsers in 5 threads maintaining seperate sessions with the server of mysite.com,

Wont the sessions overlap with each other?

EDIT : By multiple threads I meant 5 control instances in 5 separate threads. I hope this makes the COM component issue clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run the `WebBrowser` component in multiple threads to do so, as the underlying COM object is running in one native thread.

***edit***
This is clearly what it's all about. It's ONE COM object, so they will share the session. So no, it is not possible to do so.